# Spark SQL JDBC numberOfPartitions calculation from huge vs small data load

Tags: apache-spark

I have a use case where depending on the argument passed in I may have to fetch and process 1) millions or records from database (read rdbms using jdbc, decode, convert to xml, convert to csv etc., a very time consuming process), and or 2) process only a few hundres or even handful of records. Please note that I do not know the volume of the data in this multi-tenant spark app until during the runtime of my app where I calculate total # of records I need to process. So I have two questions here:

1. How do I know how many executors or cores I need to request for this spark job without knowing the data volume as I kick off the run.
2. Because I making jdbc calls on a DB table, I am using the numOfPartitions, lowerbound(0), upperBound(total#OfRecords), and partitioncolumn(ROW_NUM) to parition the SparkSQL. Now how do I calculate the numOfPartitions? In one case when I am fetching millions I want to have more paritions and less for a handful. How do I decide this number? What is the logic? Would this numOFPartition be 10-20 for 100-200? We dont want to affect transaction applications by hoggin DB resources. How do people typically decide on ths numOfPartitions?
   Appreicate your help
   thank you

Need help deciding database numOfPartitions